# How to add flexible sizing to layout components of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to add flexible sizing attributes to in XML of android layout.
I want to add elements such that the height/width of one element equals to height of parent minus another element.

Like in CSS, we can use `calc()` function
Ex: calc(100% - 100px)

Is there a way to do something similar in android, like:

I set

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

So, is there anything like:

```
<RecyclerView 
  android:layout_height = "(match_parent - ?attr/actionBarSize)"/>
```

Is there any way to achieve this **in XML itself** and not with java in the activity?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. But you can do it by using margins.

For example if you need to "cut" the height of a RelativeLayout from bottom you can use:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

or if you want to do it from the top:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that in Relative layout as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As in above code first i placed button at bottom.Now for remaining place i want to display listview. So i place listview above button and make it match_parent.So it will all remaining space.